# Passing parameters to JDBC connection in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a problem trying to setup a JDBC connection in Jmeter. What I need to do is getting a username from a first database, called A, and use that username as a connection parameter in a second JDBC connection, so I can connect to database B.

I read that the JDBC connection is loaded immediately, before any JDBC request. So I cannot pass usernames as parameters to it. How could I achieve this?

I am using the latest version of Jmeter (5.4.1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the options is getting the username in the [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-setup-thread-group-jmeter-when-preparing-load-test/), converting it into a JMeter Property using [__setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) and reading the username in the normal Thread Group using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P)

Alternative approach would be switching from JDBC Request sampler to [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and instantiate the connection (or [connection pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool)) yourself. See Working with a relational database chapter of Groovy documentation for more details.

Comment: This worked! I created a setUp Thread and configured everything about the database A in there. Then I worked with properties as suggested and into the second thread I used them as parameters for the JDBC connection for the database B. Thank you!